# Store postgres database at some other location other than data folder

Tags: postgresql

Is there any way of storing database other than the fixed data directory in postgres? I have a situation where I need to store database at any location irrespective of data directory.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a [tablespace](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/manage-ag-tablespaces.html).

A tablespace is basically a location to store databases and/or tables. You create a tablespace using [CREATE TABLESPACE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createtablespace.html):

```
CREATE TABLESPACE mytablespace LOCATION '/path/to/some/location';
```

You can then create tables directly in that tablespace:

```
CREATE TABLE whatever (thing integer) TABLESPACE mytablespace;
```

Or set the default tablespace:

```
SET default_tablespace = mytablespace;
```

You can also set the default tablespace at database creation time:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydatabase TABLESPACE mytablespace;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the 'Data Directory' in linux for example its in

/usr/local/pgsql/data

if you install from source code. Each distribution is different though, try reading up on

[File Locations in postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-file-locations.html) and [Creating a Database Cluster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/creating-cluster.html)

also try using the query

```
show data_directory;
```

in windows try looking around

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\[VERSION]\data\global
```